# View generated SQL statements used by Room

Tags: android, android-room

I'm writing migrations for my database using Room. Room requires during migrations that you manually write out the SQL statements. My database structure is quite complex to me. Is there a way I can view the SQL statements Room uses to generate the databases.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please review the help section and especially the part about how to create Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't know Room, but your question might be sufficient for people to answer. However, people don't get paid to answer. Therefore, writing what you've already tried generates good will. Searching the site for 'sql migration' and sorting by votes will give you more insight into how to answer as well as perhaps an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can see the classes that Room generates for you in `build/generated/source/apt/...`, and in there is the generated SQL.

Also, if you enabled schema logging in Gradle, you will find schemas in the designated directory:

```
javaCompileOptions {
  annotationProcessorOptions {
    arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
                     "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
  }
}
```

Comment: I added this to build.gradle. I have a test for checking my migration and it fails to saying schema version change. But I can't find the generated folder/sql queries anywhere. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @vizsatiz: I do not know. You may want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve]. I am sorry that I was unable to assist directly with your problem.

Comment: Thanks, i found what i needed it in /app/build/generated/source/kapt/{LOCATION_DATABASE/{DATABASE_NAME}_Impl.java